# Pivotal Cloud Foundry : Error while deploying app

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I am getting the following error when I am trying to deploy an app :

```
Pushing from manifest to org s / space P as l...
Using manifest file /Users/a/b/b/b/manifest.yml
Getting app info...
Unexpected Response
Response code: 503
CC code:       0
CC error code: 
Request ID:    some big uuid::some big uuid
Description:   {
  "description": "The Routing API is currently unavailable",
  "error_code": "CF-RoutingApiUnavailable",
  "code": 370001
}
```

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: What's in your manifest.yml? Can you include a sanitized version of it?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Hecking heck. Looks like the component in pcf responsible for mapping the route is not operational. I was able to deploy the app and map the route manually!